# UI freezes when I open many tabs in browser

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, chrome, freeze, adobe-flash

**When I open many tabs on browser, UI completely freezes**. In some cases I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 twenty or thirty times, after 15 minutes UI unfreeze, I switch to text terminal, kill browser and after that operating systems work fine. In other cases UI freezes completely, I'm not able to switch to text terminal and I have to reset my computer.

I'm experiencing difficulties in one of these browsers:

- Firefox with flash plugin enabled (firefox without flash works fine)
- Google Chrome (it doesn't matter if flash is enabled or disabled in
  Chrome)

When computer freezes I don't see any strange errors in syslog.

Chrome, Firefox and Flash work perfectly on my computer in Windows 7. I have no freezing issues in Windows.

My configuration is:

> Now I use Linux Mint 17.1 64-bit.
>   CPU Intel Core i5-4440 (with 4 cores)
>   8GB RAM
>   Samsung 840 EVO 250 GB SSD
>   I have 2 videos: Intel HD Graphics 4600 and GeForce GT610.
>   Swap is disabled
>   CPU cooling works perfectly
>   Memtest show no errors

In the past I had same issue with Google Chrome on different computer:

> Back then I used:
>   Scientific Linux 6.3 64-bit
>   Intel Pentium E5500
>   4 GB RAM
>   On that configuration Google Chrome was also freezing X server. If I remember correctly, flash in firefox didn't freeze UI on my old PC.

**How can protect myself from UI freezing? Should I change some linux config file to avoid freezing? What is the reason of freezing?**

Answer (score -1):

I know it is too late, and you may have already figured out the answer. From what you have written, I can sense that ,you are lacking in RAM size. If you can, please increase your RAM size. Alternatively, increase Swap area of your machine (You, can do that using 'gparted' application).

But, swap area will not be of significantly help, as the speed of swap area is pretty low as compared proper RAM. It is always advisable to increase your RAM size, as the time passes the applications like Chrome, Firefox will accumulate more data per webpage.

Thank you.